# how to control <date> markup in html5

Tags: javascript, forms, html, date

In html5 there is the excellent `<date>` which works on Opera (and partially on maxthon) like a charme.

but a user gets all dates, so for example in a form registration, how do i filter dates for a user that have under 18 years?

Comment: i downvoted so obviously someone upvoted to make it 0.

Comment: downvoting should make sense no?

Comment: Are you talking about the `<date>` element, or `<input type="date">`?

Comment: no, the date element, and that was solved and it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to only allow dates within a certain range. For this, you can specify `min="2010-01-01"` to only allow dates after the 1st January,  for instance. You can also specify `max=`. Both must be in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: but making like that will be static?
how can i made it dynamic, i guess with Javascript? but how?
and there is a problem here, if using Javascript, and the client have a bad configured system time, so i'll use Python for that (from the server) ?

Comment: so ok, now i remember that i can embeed the date from the server using the date in {{}} using Tornado :)
thank you again

Comment: Note that using server date means you might be a day out either way for perhaps several hours depending on the difference between the server and client timezones.

Comment: yes, but the page will be only for a country (Algeria) users (GMT+1)